# Relative symlinks in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, relative-path, symlink

I have a folder 'foo' which consist of file 'foo.v'. foo.v is a symlink to another file

`foo.v -> ../foo2/foo.v`

Now, I copy (or create link) another `foo.v` at first location (`foo/`) so that it becomes symlink to another file along with its original source file

```
- foo.v -> ../foo3/foo.v 
- ../foo2/foo.v -> ../foo3/foo.v
```

Is something like this possible in linux ?

Answer (score 0):

A symlink can point to a symlink:

```
$ echo test > 1
$ ln -s 1 2
$ ln -s 2 3
$ cat 3
test
$
```

These files look like this:

```
1
2 -> 1
3 -> 2
```

When moving or copying a symlink it behaves just like a file - the content is not changed:

```
$ cp 2 3
```

This would look like this:

```
1
2 -> 1
3 -> 1
```

Comment: In this case, 3 will point to 2, 2 will point to 1. 
3->2 and 2->1 . 

Is it possible that both of them point to 1 using single copy or symlink command ?